# I am developing an authentication program in python but I am having database problems

Tags: python, file-io

I am developing a login system but im having trouble with the user and password storage part. I made a list and i outsourced it to a text file and it writes everything in it but every time i run the program again it erases everything it stored previously. Here is the code i wrote until now. Anything else i am doing wrong, please let me know, i am happy to get a more skilled person's opinion on this.

```
done = True

while done == True:
    user = input('Create Username: ')

    from pwgen import genPass

    break

while done == True:    
    password = input('Create Password: ')
    done = False

    store_user = []
    store_pass = []

    store_userpass = []

    if user in store_user:
        print("That user already exists")
    else:
        store_user.append(user)
        store_pass.append(password)

        outF = open('user.txt', 'w')
        outf= open('pw.txt', 'w')

        for line in store_user:
            outF.write(line)
            outF.write('\n')

        for line1 in store_pass:
            outf.write(line1)
            outf.write('\n')

    outF.close()
    outf.close()

    done = False

while True:
    userguess=""
    passwordguess=""
    key=""
    while (userguess != user) and (passwordguess != password):
        userguess = input('User Name: ')
        passwordguess = input('Password: ')

        if userguess != user:
            print("Error: Unknown username.")
        if userguess == user and passwordguess != password:
            print("Error: Incorrect password. Try again.")
        if userguess != user and passwordguess != password:
            print("Error: Unknown user and password combination.")
        if userguess == user and passwordguess == password:
            print("Welcome,", user, ". Type lock to lock this user.")
    break

while key != "lock":
    key = input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the files `user.txt` and `pw.txt` in `write` mode (the second parameter in the `open` function), which recreates the file each time, instead of `append` mode, which will allow you to append data to your files.

Try:

```
outF = open('user.txt', 'a')
outf= open('pw.txt', 'a')
```

instead of:

```
outF = open('user.txt', 'w')
outf= open('pw.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: I didn't know there is an append mode. Thanks for the help man!